# @SpringBootApplication not detecting another @Configuration component in the same package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, component-scan

This is my project package structure.

```
org.myApp
       MainApplication.java
       org.myApp.controller
       org.myApp.repositories
       org.myApp.utils
```

I have a `@SpringBootApplication` placed in my `org.myApp.MainApplication` class and I'm expecting that it will scan all my subpackages for components as they are placed in the same package as this main class.

However, I have created this new class in `org.myApp.utils` called `Utils` which is not being picked up by the application context.

```
package org.myApp.utils;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
public class Utils {
    Utils() throws IOException{
        getAllProps();
    }
    @Bean
    public static Properties getAllProps() throws IOException{
      return new Properties();
}
}
```

The class is only scanned when I explicitly use a `@ComponentScan("org.myApp.Utils")` in my `MainApplication.java` class however this breaks the rest of my application for some reason.

How do I ensure that my Utils class is scanned and placed in the application context?

Comment: Maybe that's not the cause of your problem, but I feel, you're doing something weird in the little code snippet you provided. Why is @Bean method static? Why do you call the method from constructor?

Comment: If you remove "static" and remove your constructor, the issue persists?